# Fragments not loading in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my app, after some specific time, the server makes the user log out and redirect to the log in page. But when the user logs in again, the fragment which the user last visited before logging out does not loads properly. It keeps displaying the message as loading but it does nothing. The only option the user is left with is to stop the application, clear the cache for the app and then start it again, this time it loads properly. What might be the problem here? please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post your code

Comment: I am sorry, but I can't post the code. Can u at least give me some idea about which field to look for?